# Dynamically populating ipset list to blacklist ip addresses which match a certain iptables rule

Tags: linux, security, iptables

I've written following iptables rules:

```
iptables -N flood

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j flood

iptables -A flood -m limit --limit 1/sec --limit-burst 30 -j RETURN

iptables -A flood -j LOG --log-ip-options --log-uid --log-level 4 --log-prefix "IPTABLES: FLOOD: "

iptables -A flood -j DROP
```

I want to blacklist and block any IP address which matches this rule. How do I populate and update an ipset list on the fly to add IP addresses which match certain iptables rules. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to add the source IP address of the host which sends the traffic at more than the specified rate.

For that, you can use:

```
iptables -A flood -m limit --limit 1/sec --limit-burst 30 -j SET --add-set ipsetname src
```